# Como posso tornar esse código mais funcional em Javascript?

Tags: javascript, algoritmo, programação-funcional

Esse código resolve o problema de achar o *num*ésimo primo entre 0 e 10,000:

```
  function PrimeMover(num) { 

  var counter = 0;
  var primes = [];

  for (var i=2; i<=10000; i++){

    for (var j = 2; j<i; j++){

      if (i%j===0) { counter++ };

    }

    if (counter === 0) { primes.push(i) };
    counter = 0;

  }

  return primes[num-1]

}
```

Gostaria de uma ajuda, sobre como resolver o problema usando programação funcional de Javascript.

Comment: Um pouco vaga a pergunta, não?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

A questão acaba envolvendo mais matemática do que programação em si, como não sou nenhum expert em matemática vou tentar explicar da forma mais simples e leiga.

Como descobrir se um número é **primo**? Simples, só pode ser divisível por 1 por ele mesmo.

Ao invés de seguir essa regra porque não procurar pelos números que são divisíveis por algum número diferente de 1 e ele mesmo? Partindo daqui você já elimina metade dos números até seu valor.

Seus possíveis divisores terá a seguinte fórmula:

[image: inserir a descrição da imagem aqui]

Pra implementar:

```
function PrimeMover(num) {
    var encontrados = 1;
    var primos = [2];

    // já temos o [2] então posso partir do [3]
    var numero = 3; 

    // vai rodar quantas vezes forem necessárias até encontrar o enésimo número
    while (encontrados < num) {
        var numeroPrimo = true;

        // implementação da nossa regra, procura pelos valores até metade
        for (i=2; i <= Math.sqrt(numero); i++) {
            if (numero % i == 0) {
                numeroPrimo = false;
                break;
            }
        }

        // se for numero primo adiciona na lista e incrementa os encontrados pra saber quando parar
        if (numeroPrimo) {
            primos.push(numero);
            encontrados++;
        }
        numero++;
    }

    return primos[num-1];
}
```

Comment: Esse seu algoritmo não é muito diferente do que o OP já tem... BTW, prefiro evitar a raiz quadrada via `i*i < numero`. Assim não tem que se preocupar se tem algum erro de arredondamento.

Answer (score 5):

A sugestão que eu faria é fazer um [crivo de erastostenes](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Sieve_of_Eratosthenes) de verdade ao invés de um algoritmo de "trial division"

```
function PrimeMover(num) { 

  var N = 10000;
  var isPrime = [];
  isPrime[0] = false;
  isPrime[1] = false;
  for (var i=2; i <= N; i++){
      isPrime[i] = true;
  }

  var primes = [];
  for (var i=2; i <= N; i++){
    if(!isPrime[i]) continue;

    primes.push(i);
    for (var j = 2*i; j <= N; j += i){
      isPrime[i] = false;
    }
  }

  return primes[num-1]
}
```

Esse algoritmo é bastante mais eficiente do que o que você está usando. Ele tem complexidade `O(N log log N)` enquanto o algoritmo de testar os divisores tem complexidade `O((N/log n)^2)`

Quanto a deixar o código mais funcional, não sei se vale a pena. É não trivial escrever o crivo de erastostenes sem usar uma vetor e a maioria dos algoritmos funcionais pra calcular primos que se vê por aí são ineficientes como o código da sua pergunta: http://cs.hmc.edu/~oneill/papers/Sieve-JFP.pdf

Comment: +1; outros algoritmos difíceis de implementar funcionalmente são o _union-find_. O livro do [Chris Okasaki](http://www.cs.cmu.edu/~rwh/theses/okasaki.pdf) tem muita coisa legal sobre algoritmos e estruturas de dados funcionais.

Answer (score 1):

Os principais conceitos do paradigma funcional são *funções de alta ordem* (funções que recebem outras funções como argumentos) e *ausência de efeitos colaterais*. Os programas são escritos como composições de funções, ao invés de procedimentos sequenciais.

Para resolver este problema, podemos definir o resultado desejado como a *lista de números que passa por um teste de primalidade*.

Começamos gerando uma lista (um array, na verdade) de candidatos:

```
var candidatos = [];
for (var i = 2; i <= 10000; i++) {
    candidatos.push(i);
}
```

E, desses candidatos, queremos separar os que passam em um teste de primalidade. Definimos o nosso teste:

```
var teste_primo = function (n) {
    for (var i=2; i*i <= n; i++)
    if (n%i == 0)
        return false;
    return true;
}
```

E, por fim, filtramos dos candidatos os que passam no teste:

```
candidatos.filter(teste_primo)
```

Note que a função filter recebe como argumento outra função - o nosso teste de primalidade. Ela aplica o teste nos números e retorna um novo array contendo somente os que passam no teste.

Podemos usar a mesma função, para, por exemplo, separar os pares:

```
candidatos.filter (function (n) {return n % 2 == 0})
```

(Note que eu defini a função ao mesmo tempo que a passei como parâmetro - não preciso dar um nome a ela se eu for usá-la somente uma vez, o que é comum no paradigma funcional).

É importante notar, que, exceto à declaração de nossa lista de candidatos, nenhuma das nossas funções gerou efeitos colaterais (alteração de variáveis externas, etc). Nós definimos funções e compomos essas funções para obter o resultado como retorno.

Outra consequência é que se quisermos alterar nosso teste de primalidade para algo mais eficiente, precisamos somente fornecer outra função ao invés de *teste_primo*. O teste de primalidade está isolado do resto da lógica do programa.

Por fim, a função filter já é implementada na linguagem, mas poderíamos implementar a nossa própria versão. O que ela faz é receber uma array, um teste, e retorna um array com os elementos que passam no teste:

```
var meu_filter = function (arr, teste){
    var saida = []
    for (var i = 0; i <= arr.length; i++)
    if (teste(arr[i])){
        saida.push(i)
    }
    return saida
}
```

Testando:

```
< meu_filter(candidatos,teste_primo)
> Array [ 2, 3, 5, 7, 11, 13, 17, 19, 23, 29, 1219 mais… ]
```